# ngrx/store-devtools actionsBlocklist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, redux-devtools

Hello I would like not display one of my actions in extension Redux DevTools. I thought I could do it with property actionBlocklist but when I wrote this:

```
 StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25,
      logOnly: environment.production,
      actionsBlocklist: ['[ACTION] NAME_OF_ACTION'] }),
```

nothing is change. I'm sure that name of action is same as name from redux. Maybe I misunderstanding concept of this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it's using a regex check under the hood.
Because the action name contains of `[` and `]`, the check will fail and won't block the action.

Unfortunately the typings don't allow a regex to be passes, but as a workaround you can do:

```
actionsBlocklist: [/\[ACTION\] NAME_OF_ACTION/.source]
```